# jQuery.inArray conditional returning false despite element existing within json array

Tags: php, jquery, json

What I'm attempting to do is invoke the loading of data from mysql into a php that's being called through jQuery then `json_encode` the array and send it via `header('Content-type: application/json')` to the jQuery function that's going to subsequently process the array as data for updating specific elements on the page.

I'm at the final lap here, having jQuery making the call, php accessing the database and sending the data back as a json array to the main page and getting most of the elements updated with their fresh data. Where I'm stuck is at analyzing a specific attribute of one element of the array: determining if a specified element exists in the array and, if so, disabling and hiding an input element.

What is being returned by the call is "btn1:true" ("true" being an arbitrary value) and no matter how I approach checking its existence, inArray gives me a -1, meaning that, even though it is making it through as an element of the array, my code is failing to find it.

Here is the code that makes the call and processes the incoming data:

```
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#refresh').click(function () {
        $.get('includes/refresh.php', function (data) {
            if (jQuery.inArray(btn1, data) > -1) {
                $('#btn1').prop("disabled", true);
                $('#btn1').hide();
            }
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cckSj/41/), though without understanding exactly what format the array is in, getting positive results here doesn't help.

Here's the code that's called to pull data from mysql and send it back as a json array:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $divs = array ();
    $divs['item'] = $row['item'];
    $divs['cost'] = "Ticket price: ".$row['cost'];
    for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
        $divs['tname'.$i] = $row['t'.$i];
        if ($row['t'.$i] != "") {
            $divs['btn'.$i] = "true";
        }
    }
    $divs['end'] = $row['end'];
    $divs['winner'] = $row['winner'];
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($divs);
    die();
} else {
    // nothing to refresh. clear the page and prompt user to start a new raffle.
}
```

... and here's the button that I totally want to make disappear:

```
<input id="btn1" class="submit" name="t1" type="submit" value="Buy!" />
```

So, to sum: the call is functioning, the data is being dragged from mysql and compiled into an a json-encoded array that's subsequently being passed to and being received by the calling script. My element check is failing to find what I know to be in the array. What am I overlooking?

Comment: the said response `"btn1:true"` is not an array

Comment: You're using btn_1 is a variable `btn_1` not a string literal `'btn_1'`

Comment: also what is the value of the variable `btn1` did you mean the string literal `btn1` here

Comment: It's an example of what is in the array, albeit a poor syntax. What is being returned is exactly this:

`{"item":"200,000,00","cost":"Ticket price: 2500","tname1":"test","btn1":"true","tname2":"","tname3":"","tname4":"","tname5":"test","btn5":"true","tname6":"test","btn6":"true","tname7":"","tname8":"","tname9":"","tname10":"","tname11":"","tname12":"","tname13":"","tname14":"","tname15":"","tname16":"","tname17":"","tname18":"","tname19":"","end":"0","winner":""}`

Of course, that's a lot of irrelevance. ;)

Comment: Try using jQuery.parseJSON
`if (jQuery.inArray(btn1, jQuery.parseJSON(data)) > -1) {`

Comment: In your given code, you've put `< script type = "text/javascript" >` but there is no space after `<` in your actual code is there?

Comment: There is not and I'm not sure how those spaces got here. Then again, I've been awake for nearly 24 hours. Spaces are starting look a lot like semicolons and rogue underscores have me moderately distracted. :D

Thanks again for the help, man. And quick, too. I wasn't expecting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things. Use [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) instead of `get` because you're getting JSON.

```
$.getJSON('includes/refresh.php', function (data)...`
```

And, you're sending this data

```
$divs['btn'.$i] = "true";
// which gives $divs['btn1'] = "true";
```

but you're using btn1 as a variable not a string literal

```
if (jQuery.inArray(btn1, data) > -1)  {
```

and it's a KEY not a variable in the array.

It should read

```
if (data.btn1) {
// or to be really specific:
// if (typeof data.btn1!='undefined' && data.btn1)
```

Also, while `"true"` IS truthy, so is `"false"`, I think you mean `$divs['btn'.$i] = true;`

Also also (it's not part of the problem but...)

```
$('#btn1').prop("disabled", true);
$('#btn1').hide();
```

There's no need to keep selecting the element. Chain the commands.

```
$('#btn1').prop("disabled", true).hide();
```

Every time you select it, jQuery has to search for it. If you can't chain them, set a variable once. `$btn=$('#btn1');` and use that `$btn1.hide(); $btn1.show(); ...`.

Comment: "True" IS truthy... and mostly arbitrary. I only need the element itself to get to the truth of this matter. String or boolean or int or float would serve the purpose of lowly placeholder. :)

And, huzza! I was looking everywhere in the code for that rogue underscore. It appears that my JSFiddle was fiddled with too much... or not enough, even. The removal of underscores in code didn't make it into testing.

Having a closer look now. Thanks for the direction so far. :)

Comment: That was an aside. The real problems were highlighted too.

Comment: Thank you. I'll need a few moments to apply your suggestions. :)

Comment: You, sir, have just sorted out a 6 hour facepalm/head-desk session. Thank you very much.